# Wordpress Adding Lines to my Theme Files

Tags: themes

Has anyone else noticed that sometimes, after uploading a theme, when you download it or edit it via Wordpress there are line breaks in between every line? For instance:

`1 First line`

`2 Second line`

Becomes

`1 First line`

`2`

`3 Second line`

I've randomly run into this several times and I've always wondered if there was a cure? Any ideas? Maybe I'm just super OCD but I love tight lines of code!

Comment: One solution could be to download a FTP Client of choice and edit your theme files that way versus the admin editor.

Comment: See, the weird thing is that sometimes it seems to start when I go through FTP, sometimes through the admin editor, I've just got no idea where the issue comes from.

Comment: Are you using a Mac to edit the files? Some programs are still using `\r` line endings.